# I am Working in xamarin forms, I have created class Broadcast receiver but ONReceive () is not getting called? how to trigger this method or called?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created below code , It is my bluetoothDeviceReciver class which is created in Xamarin forms Android Project. I am trying to broadcast device id or some common thing so that I will know the device count which uses the same app.

class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

```
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var action = intent.Action;
        if (action != BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
        {
            return;
        }
        var device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
       
        if (device.BondState != Bond.Bonded)
        {
            var name = device.Name;
            var address = device.Address;
       
        }         
    }
}
```

and In main activity OnCreate()

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _receiver = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();
         RegisterReceiver(_receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound));
        BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.StartDiscovery();

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("RadioButton_Experimental");
     
        RequestPermissions(permissionArr, RequestId);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
```

}

This OnRecieve() is not getting called , I am not getting why exactly? After getting all device addreess I have to store it in file which is in PCL project,
so I need device address in PCL project as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Puja You can use dependency injection to achieve the same

Comment: Is your issue about `OnReceive` method cannot be executed or you want to send the data from android to the pcl, If this question about  `OnReceive` cannot execute, can you share your BroadcasetReceiver code. If your question about send data, MessagingCenter to achieve it, you can refer to this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26681/need-to-get-message-back-to-forms-pcl-from-android-prj